# The member does not exist? Powershell script

Tags: powershell, adsi

I have been reading some questions and can find information on creating scripts but none seemingly using the object type "Computer".

Apologies if this is more suited to superuser. But this is still at the script level and as such I thought it would be best placed here.

Here is my script. I want to add a domain registered Server (Computer) to the performance monitor users group on a range of servers.

```
$ComputerName = Read-Host "Remote Computer name:"
$PmuGroup = [ADSI]"WinNT://$ComputerName/Performance Monitor Users,group"
$User = [ADSI]"WinNT://DOMAIN/ServerName,computer"
$PmuGroup.Add($User.Path)
```

The following error is displayed:

```
Exception calling "Add" with "1" argument(s): "A member could not be added to 
or removed from the local group because
the member does not exist.
"
At line:1 char:1
+ $AdminGroup.Add($User.Path)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CatchFromBaseAdapterMethodInvokeTI
```

If I enter `$user` into PS, it returns the Path and seemingly finds the machine.

Tried without .path as suggested in comments;

```
PS C:\WINDOWS> $PmuGroup.Add($User)
Exception calling "Add" with "1" argument(s): "Type mismatch. (Exception 
from HRESULT: 0x80020005
(DISP_E_TYPEMISMATCH))"
At line:1 char:1
+ $PmuGroup.Add($User)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CatchFromBaseAdapterMethodInvokeTI
```

Is this an error with my script / can anyone please advise on any errors in it? 
For info : Domain/ServerName is not what is being used. I have removed the actual name from here.

Comment: Have you tried `$PmuGroup.Add($User)`?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Yes, slightly different error. I have amended the question.

Comment: Try doing this manually on one server (with the GUI, or `net localgroup`) and see if it spits out the same (or a comparable) error, to ensure it's just your script that's not working and eliminate the possibility that something in AD itself is broken. Also, is this script executed locally on the server or remotely through `Invoke-Command`? The latter can cause double hop authentication issues when having to verify something against the domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The samAccountName of a computer account always ends with a `$`:

```
$ComputerName = Read-Host "Remote Computer name:"
$PmuGroup = [ADSI]"WinNT://$ComputerName/Performance Monitor Users,group"
$Computer = [ADSI]"WinNT://DOMAIN/ServerName$"
$PmuGroup.Add($Computer.Path)
```

Comment: @Bill_Stewart Strange.  Works fine for me.  I'm on Win 7/PS 5.1, remote system is Server 2012 R2/PS 4.

Comment: Thank you so much. This has worked. I didn't realise the computer account had to end with $, nor did I realise you didn't need the object type "computer" after it. This works perfectly.